# Hardcoded manifest start url still not found?

Tags: wordpress, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I am attempting to setup a WordPress Theme as a Progressive Web App. When I run Chromes Audit tool (lighthouse?) I get an uninformative error that I don't know what exactly the problem is. The error is:

> Failures: Service worker does not successfully serve the manifest start_url. Unable to fetch start url via service worker

I have hardcoded my start url which is a valid url. Any suggestions on what the issue could be?

`https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/web.manifest`:

```
  ...
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "https://mywebsite.com",
  "serviceworker": {
    "src": "dist/assets/sw/service-worker.js",
    "scope": "/aw/",
    "update_via_cache": "none"
  },
  ...
}
```

`https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/dist/assets/sw/service-worker.js`:

```
...
// The fetch handler serves responses for same-origin resources from a cache.
// If no response is found, it populates the runtime cache with the response
// from the network before returning it to the page.
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Skip cross-origin requests, like those for Google Analytics.
  if (event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(cachedResponse => {
        if (cachedResponse) {
          return cachedResponse;
        }

        return caches.open(RUNTIME).then(cache => {
          return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
            // Put a copy of the response in the runtime cache.
            return cache.put(event.request, response.clone()).then(() => {
              return response;
            });
          });
        });
      })
    );
  }
});
```

I register my SW with the following code and it outputs that it has successfully registered the SW:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register(Vue.prototype.$ASSETS_PATH + 'sw/service-worker.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Please change your start_url to

```
 "start_url": "/"
```

It has to be a relative url. Please see the [documentaion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

[image]